# Several projects sharing same database (Spring JAVA)

Tags: java, spring, git

I am facing one problem and not sure what is the best way to go,

So I have two git repositories with Spring projects which have to share the same database. (Both are spring projects with hibernate).

One of them is main project so-called **MASTER** which should modify all Hibernate entities and other I will call **SLAVE** which is secondary project and needs to read only from the same database.

Here is the small illustration what I have.

[image]

So the issue appears when I realized that need to keep the duplicate of entities in both master and slave.

I found two ways to go with this issue.

1. Using *git submodules*. Where I can have my entities to be an independent submodule.
2. Building a JAR from entity classes and include it in both projects.

This both solutions are not meeting my requirements which are:

The solution of submodules is not good because whenever I commit anything from the MASTER I want SLAVE to track that changes. Please note, I have 3 git branches for both projects, master, staging and production. So all the branches should have accordingly their version of entities.

The solution of the jars will work, just I do not find it nice and solid, as I should all the time build them and add a dependency for every project.

The development of these projects is done independently from each other.

Please, could you share your opinion on this issue? 
I kind of sure that I am not only the one who is trying to achieve the same.

Comment: I'd go with the jar approach. Make a maven module out of it and you can easily keep track of versioning too.

Comment: Did you do something like that already?

Comment: Should I make 3 different Maven Modules for each branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider publishing your jar to a maven repository for easier exchange between the projects. You could even host your own like sonar nexus. https://www.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-sonatype

Personally, I think that managing the versions can be very annoying when you have multiple projects. Especially when you are testing something and you have to create a new jar and then publish it over and over again. However your project will be rebuildable and you can controll which project/module can use a newer version of your entity-dependency.

Comment: I will still love to have some other solution, as still, this makes things complicated.